# How can I find the type of a property dynamically in swift (Reflection/Mirror)?

Tags: ios, swift, reflection

So let's say I have a class like this:

```
class Employee: NSObject {
    var id: String?
    var someArray: [Employee]?
}
```

I use reflection to get the property names:

```
let employee = Employee()
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: employee)
propertyNames = mirror.children.flatMap { $0.label } 
// ["businessUnitId", "someArray"]
```

so far so good! Now i need to be able to figure out the type of each of these properties, so if I do the `employee.valueForKey("someArray")`, it won't work because it only gives me the AnyObject type. What would be the best way to do this? Specially for the array, I need to be able to dynamically tell that the array contains type of `Employee`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need to inherit from `NSObject` (unless you have a good reason to).

```
class Employee {
    var id: String?
    var someArray: [Employee]?
}

let employee = Employee()

for property in Mirror(reflecting: employee).children {
    print("name: \(property.label) type: \(type(of: property.value))")
}
```

Output

```
name: Optional("id") type: Optional<String>
name: Optional("someArray") type: Optional<Array<Employee>>
```

> This also works with Structs

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: property.value.dynamicType returns nil if the value is nil

Answer (score 0):

```
employee.valueForKey("someArray")!.dynamicType
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are inheriting from `NSObject`, you can use some of the methods provided by `NSCoding` and the Objective-C runtime:

```
let employee = Employee()
employee.someArray = []
employee.valueForKey("someArray")?.classForCoder // NSArray.Type
employee.valueForKey("someArray")?.classForKeyedArchiver // NSArray.Type
employee.valueForKey("someArray")?.superclass // _SwiftNativeNSArrayWithContiguousStorage.Type
```